# Service worker not registering on vite react app

Tags: reactjs, vite, service-worker

For a while now I have been trying to register service worker for my vite react app but for some odd reason it not registering in production environment, while it does on localhost.

Below is my vite configuration:

```
import { defineConfig } from "vite";
import react from "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc";
import svgr from "vite-plugin-svgr";

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react(), svgr()],
  build: {
    outDir: "build",
    rollupOptions: {
      external:['./service-worker.js'],
      output: {
        manualChunks(id) {
          if (id.includes("node_modules")) {
            return "vendor";
          }
        },
      },
    },
  },
  server: {
    hmr:{
overlay: false,
    },
    proxy: {
      "/api": {
        target: "http://localhost:8000",
        changeOrigin: true,
        secure: false,
        ws: true,
        logLevel: "debug",
        onProxyReq: function (proxyReq, req, res) {
          proxyReq.setHeader("Content-Length", req.body.length);
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

I have tried registering it in my app entry point, calling the service worker file from the root directory, but it's not working.

Comment: What do you mean by "registering"? Do you mean whether its not bundled in your code as a separate file?

Comment: Yes it's not...

Comment: Thats what `external` means. To not bundle in your output code.

Comment: I suppose the build folder should contain service-worker.js as a separate file, instead of bundling it with others, that's why I used external, but it's still not working though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrectly used the `rollupOptions.external`.

`external` just means vite will ignore it and not put it in the output directory.

If what you want is to have your `service-worker.js` in your output directory, you can use the `vite-plugin-static-copy` plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-static-copy

```
import { viteStaticCopy } from 'vite-plugin-static-copy'

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    viteStaticCopy({
      targets: [
        {
          src: './service-worker.js', // correct path to this file.
          dest: './', // root of your output directory
        },
      ],
    }),
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You maybe asking a [XY Problem](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) here: I'm guessing you simply need to be able to use `service-worker.js` as a service worker script. To achieve this, there's no need to statically copy anything. Simply replace

```
'service-worker.js'
```

in your code with

```
new URL('service-worker.js', import.meta.url)
```

`vite` will automatically replace `./service-worker.js` with the generated js script. This works even if you wrote the service worker in typescript.

Reference: https://v3.vitejs.dev/guide/features.html#web-workers