# Vite Web App Works in Incognito Mode but Not in Regular Browsing Mode

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vite, service-worker, rollup

I just initialized a vite app, `vite + React + Typescript`.

Here are the steps I followed

```
Eh@little: yarn create vite

✔ Project name: … My-app-typescript
✔ Package name: … My-app-typescript
✔ Select a framework: › React
✔ Select a variant: › TypeScript

Eh@little: cd My-app-typescript
Eh@little:~/My-app-typescript$ yarn
Eh@little:~/My-app-typescript$ yarn dev
```

Only a couple of dots get rendered. No Errors.

In the console, there is this one error/message

`Fetch intercepted for http://localhost:5173/   service-worker.js:34`

This is my second time. The App works fine on other browsers and in incognito mode.

I tried uninstalling some Chrome extensions

Comment: as far as I know, setting up a React project with Vite should typically not generate a `service-worker.js` file, so you should add details of your folder structure to know where it's coming from, particularly look out for that file. also your `package.json` file

Comment: also, if you're adding the file yourself, have a look at this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77060604/service-worker-not-registering-on-vite-react-app?rq=2